# Assigning a 2D array into a different 2D array (Python)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I've been having a problem in arrays in Python3.4.I was trying to assign an array into a bigger one, specifying its indexes.

For example, when i write the following program,

```
test=np.zeros((4,4))
test2=np.zeros((2,2))
test2[:,:]=2
test[[1,2],1:3]=test2
print(test)
```

This gives a result like

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

However, when I slightly change the program to

```
test=np.zeros((4,4))
test2=np.zeros((2,2))
test2[:,:]=2
test[[1,2],[1,2]]=test2
print(test)
```

This gives me an error

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)
```

I do not understand the difference between the 2 programs.
I wanted to choose the indices of the arrays which were going to be assigned.

---

I am sorry my question was unclear.
I wanted to achieve a matrix like

```
[[0,0,0,0],
 [0,2,0,2],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,2,0,2]]
```

by writing a program by

```
test[[1,3],[1,3]]=test2
```

but this gave me the ValueError. Is there a way to write this properly?

Comment: Change `test[[1,2],[1,2]]=test2` to `test[1:3,1:3] = test2`

Comment: Thank you four your quick reply.
I should have made my point clearer.
In the end, I was hoping to make an array like,
[[0,0,0,0],
[0,2,0,2]
[0,0,0,0]
[0,2,0,2]]
by writing a code like
test[[1,3],[1,3]]=test2
but, this didn't work. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Can you expand your question, to reflect what you want to achieve?